# Expo Push Notification - how to increase Icon Badge by 1

Tags: push-notification, expo, badge

I want to increase app icon badge by 1 when expo push notification comes.

Here's my code:

```
sendNotification({
  to: route.params.user.pushToken,
  title: `${person.username} size mesaj gönderdi`,
  body: `${messages[0].text}`,
  badge: 1,
  "content-available": 1,
  data: { url: "myApp://ChatList", type: "chat" },
});
```

Can you help me how can I listen to push notification? Or can you specify how to do badge + 1 on the server side?

Comment: There is probably no way to increase the number of badges I've written here, but if there's a logic you can suggest, I'd be very happy.

Comment: I guess that's unlikely. What needs to be done is to manage notifications on the backend side.